# MapFragment in a fragment Vs MapView in a fragment with Google Maps api v2

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an app having actionbar where one of the fragments contain a mapFragment. Also, i've to make an overlay of list on top of the map. MapFragment as of now as lesser functionality(i cant make setInfoWindowAdapter to work in it).So my question is should I be using Mapview within a fragment or MapFragment within in a fragment? which is the best practice?
 I've read through many articles but none them exactly mention which is the best option and why.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct if done correct.

Fragments inside fragments are supported as of support library v11.

Two things to remember:

1. you cannot put MapFragment to xml
2. you have to use getChildFragmentManager

Check this link for how to correctly add MapFragment inside your fragment: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5064#c1

Comment: Yeah, i have the mapfragment working inside the fragment. Just wanted an opinion thank u!